# SQL Database constantly resetting after restart

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I created a database following exactly this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdDkFPO_nto

But when I restart the computer, the tables I created are deleted everytime. I created them in Visual Studio (right click, create new table, type in the columns, click Update, Update OK) and tried to use them (check if the data exists via C#, printing the items of the columns (rows) to the console) and it worked. I closed Visual Studio, opend it again and everything works fine, I can execute the code multiple times without any issues. But when I restart the PC, all tables are gone. I also tried creating the tables in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17, with the same outcome - everything cleared after restart.

How to correctly save the data/the tables?

here is the App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="provider" value="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <add key="connectionString" value="Data Source=ANGELUS-PC;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </appSettings>

    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why are you creating the tables in `tempdb`?  That's for temporary tables...  They don't just disappear on restart, they disappear if you close your connection and re-open it.

Comment: @MatBailie `temdb` is not per-connection.

Comment: If you had stopped and started again SQL Server service the same behavior would have happened.

Comment: When I followed the tutorial, I had to give my database a name at some point - I then, stupidly, decided to name it "tempDB" without realizing, there is actually one already existing "tempdb" if I understand you correctly. (I just wanted to continue with the tutorial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the tables in the SQL Server temporal (internal) database. It is a system database not intended to users. Create a different database and use it.